# Get document from Document Library using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I am trying to get a document from document library.I am getting the file but I can't get its binary value.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: fileUrl,
    binaryStringResponseBody: true,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": 'digest'
    },
    type: "GET"
})
.done(Function.createDelegate(this, readFileSuccess))
.error(Function.createDelegate(this, readFileFailure));
```

but it didn't give me a binary value for the file. I need to get binary value and store it to local storage ( Web SQL ).

How to get the binary value?

Comment: Is FileURL direct link of file or is it a REST query?

Comment: i am using direct link

Answer (score 0):

You can use success handler for reading file content

```
function readFileSuccess(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

**Update**

```
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(weburl);
var info = {
    url: fileContentUrl,
    method: "GET",
    binaryStringResponseBody: true,
    success: function (data) {
        //binary data available in data.body
        var result = data.body;
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
};
executor.executeAsync(info);
```

Comment: yes i have used that but it doesnt give me a binary data

Comment: You should use `SP.RequestExecutor` to read in binary format. Take a look at this link http://techmikael.blogspot.no/2013/07/how-to-copy-files-between-sites-using.html

Comment: its also give me same result

Comment: You can convert it to binary using http://jsfiddle.net/bdgNZ/2/

Comment: both binary are different.. if i convert that data to binary and if i get binary value from server side code. document is corrupted after converting that